# Server-Sent Events ignoring Retry

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am fairly new here (just joined now actually).

First and foremost, thanks for any replies and possible fixes for this, now here is my problem;

I am creating my own type of chatroom within a website, it sends data to the client via Server-Sent Events but there is one Major problem. It is far too slow!

I have tried over and over again to get it to send data more often with no avail.

Here's my code below;

```
    echo "retry: 400".PHP_EOL;
echo "data: ";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<tr><td class="user">'.$row['Username'].'</td><td class="text">'.base64_decode($row['Message']).'</td><td class="time">'.$row['DateT'].' [GMT]</td></tr>';
    }
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
```

The thing is, everything sends fine and dandy, shows up on the page perfectly fine but it's just painstakingly slow (takes EXACTLY 3 seconds to receive more data)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must include a newline after the retry ex. `echo "retry: 10000\n" . PHP_EOL;`